# EXCEPTION: Response with status: 0 for URL: null in angular2

Tags: angular, flask, flask-restful

I'm getting following exception, when I'm trying to connect to remote API using anguar2 http. Also my web server is receiving request and responding properly.

I'm able to make a successful curl request to the local server.

```
EXCEPTION: Response with status: 0 for URL: null
```

service.ts

```
getAllProducts(): Observable<string> {
      return this.http.get(this.productUrl)
      .map(this.extractData)
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    console.log(body)
    return body.data || { };
}
```

Comment: Not sure but try to do it if it works.. Chang> `Observable<string> to Observable<any>` and `return body.data|| {} to return body||{}`

Comment: No luck, still getting the same exception. I believe this is something to do with the response which I'm getting from server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will helps someone.

The problem was with resource definition. When I'm trying to connect to remote resource using angular2 `http.get`, I was getting following error

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at …
```

FIX:

As I'm using `flask-restful` to build remote API, below fix solved my problem

```
from flask_restful.utils import cors
from flask_restful import Api

api = Api(app, decorators=[cors.crossdomain(origin='*')])
```

Complete source code will be available here : [inventory-manager](https://github.com/asifpy/inventory-manager)

Comment: Where is 'Api'? What libary should I import ?

Comment: You need to import it from flask-restful package like this `from flask_restful import Api`, you can check the complete source code here https://github.com/asifpy/inventory-manager

Comment: Buddy, u said in question that you're trying to access your own server but no success you used cors, why? Did you implemented to block cross origin request on your own server? Buddy i made my own server api(mean application)with express but getting same error, no luck

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error with a MEAN2 app. All I had to do was install the [CORS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) middleware and use it with express.

Comment: Getting same error installed and used cors Middleware, no luck, could you give working example

Comment: getting the same error with what? You should post a new question with your code.

Comment: already posted question, have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144243/err-connection-closed-exception-response-with-status-0-for-url-null?noredirect=1#comment69491176_41144243

Comment: @blackHawk link is dead

Comment: Its old, i probably deleted, In this case i was using wrong url, thats why i was getting this issue

Answer (score 4):

Server unavailable issue, might be CORS or server went down.

Comment: This isn't an especially helpful answer, considering the question was asked 8 months earlier and already has an accepted answer.

Comment: @Claies, Though it has an accepted answer, the question is rather more generic! And the accepted answer might not solve the issue for every visiting user.

Comment: @AshishRanjan perhaps, but this doesn't provide an answer or any actionable solution.  This is a theory, and is a comment at best.

Comment: Agree, should have been a comment.

Comment: He didn't provide a backend technology