# Angular 2 Interfaces - Noob alert

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

I'm a noob in this Typescript world and Angular2, so maybe the question can cause funny reactions.

In my app I need to retrieve data from a WS REST, the data comes in Json format.

```
data:                     Object
  outCurpacatens:         [1]
      0:                  Object
            agenda:       877
            codestado:    1
            correlativo:  1
            estado:       "RESERVADO"
            idreserva:    18142568
            idservicio:   2
            idsucursal:   2
            materno:      "MAT6398674"
            nombre:       "FELIPE ALEJANDRO"
            obs:          null
  mensaje:                null
```

And my Interface looks like:

```
export interface Agenda {
   agenda: number;
   codestado: number;
   correlativo: number;
   estado: String;
   idreserva: number;
   idservicio: number;
   idsucursal: number;
   materno: String;
   nombre: String;
   obs: String;
}
```

**agenda.components.ts**

```
export class AgendaComponent implements OnInit {

 public localState: any;
 public es: any;
 public res: any;
 public jsonData: any;

 constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute, private auth: Auth, private agendService: AgendaService) {
 }   

  public ngOnInit() {
 }

 testPatch(){
   this.res = this.agendService.getAgendaByDate('12')
              .subscribe(data => {
                                    this.jsonData = data;
                                  }
      );
 }
```

}

**agendaService.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AgendaService {

    private baseUrl = 'https://myweb';
    private serviceUrl = '/agenda/getmethod';
    private headers: Headers;

    constructor(private http:Http, private authService: Auth){
    }

    private getOptions(): RequestOptions {
        let headers: Headers = new Headers();
        let token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
        headers.append('content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer '+ token);
        let opts = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
        opts.headers = headers;
        return opts;
    }

    getAgendaByDate(fecha:string): Observable<Agenda> {
         /** input parameters setted with cons until resolve issue **/
         return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}${this.serviceUrl}?id=877&fecha=23082017`)
        .map((res: Response) => {
                                    res.json();
                                }, this.getOptions());
    }

}
```

In the compilation I get this Error:

**agenda/agenda.component.ts (52,59): Property 'outCurpacatens' does not exist on type 'Agenda'.**

I know there's something I'm missing, but I don't know what.

**EDIT UPDATE:**

Now I have put this:

**agendaService.ts**

```
 getAgendaByDate() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}${this.serviceUrl}?id=877&fecha=23082017`)
    .map((res: Response) => {return res.json().data.outCurpacatens[0]}).catch(this.handleError);
}


handleError(error) {
    console.error(error);
    console.log("Error: "+error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
}
```

And I'm getting this, in the console:

**Console**

```
Object { _body: error, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: Object, type: 3, url: null }  main.bundle.js:161:9
Error: Response with status: 0  for URL: null
```

Regards.

Comment: Well it doesn't :) I think based on what I am seeing, you want to extract the data from `outCurpacatens`´like `.map(res => res.json().data.outCurpacatens[0])`

Comment: The error references an error in the component, can you provide that code so we can see it?

Comment: @raykrow I added agendaService and agenda.component.

Comment: @MBrownG What's this `getOptions()` why are you calling it where you are, meaning after http-request?

Comment: @AJT_82 doesn't matter too much, if you remove getOptions nothing change. Still can't retrieve the data from the json to my front end (even if I put {{ jsonData }} on it, I'm not so noob xD ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `return` in your mapping, it should look like this:

```
.map((res: Response) => { return res.json() }
```

Once this is done, you maybe want to extract the object inside the array that corresponds `Agenda` in your response. That would mean the first (and only) object in the array `outCurpacatens`, so how to get a hold of that object would be:

```
.map((res: Response) => { return res.json().data.outCurpacatens[0]})
```

Also, since you have an interface, make use of it and declare the variable as the type. I assume that would be `jsonData`, so instead declare it:

```
jsonData: Agenda = <Agenda>{};
```

Once this is done, you would probably need to use the safe navigation operator to safeguard null values, like:

```
{{jsonData?.myProperty}}
```

or wrap your template in an `*ngIf="jsonData"`

hope this helps! :)

**Update:** Make sure you are calling `testPatch` from somewhere. Here's a

### [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/DzX6kAohyD7VGom7KsBi?p=preview)

where `testPatch` is called in `ngOnInit`. The code should work if you are receiving your data properly.

Comment: Have you made sure that you are receiving the data properly? I guess you have checked the network tab, but just make sure, so that we can at least eliminate that issue :)

Comment: Updated answer, please compare your code with the one in the plunker. If you still don't get the code to work, could you please try and reproduce the issue in a Plunker and I'd be happy to take a look :)

Comment: Thanks @AJT_82 your Demo works fine, but I'm still getting an Error. I have updated the question with it. Maybe is the server side?

Comment: Yes, seems like it could be server side. Have you checked that you are receiving data in the browser developer tools (network tab)?

Comment: Yeap, without a problem. Status Code: Green light  200 OK(I'm using Firefox). In the response tab, everything looks fine. Time 1ms.

Comment: Have you checked these, mentions cors issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520209/angular-2-exception-response-with-status-0-for-url-null and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38286250/exception-response-with-status-0-for-url-null-in-angular2

Comment: finally it seems to be a CORS problem. I installed the CORS extension in chrome and work well.

Comment: Yes and you needed to make the changes like in the answer right? :) Well, good that you got your CORS issue solved :)

Comment: It helps a lot to discover the problem, so maybe I have to mark your answer as correct and thanks a lot.