# Angular 2 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 0 for URL: null

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

My application is an `ASP.NET Core 1.0 Web API`. 
Iam developing the frontend with `Angular 2` and `typescript`.

If I refresh the website before it completely loaded in `Google Chrome` everything works fine but, if I do the same thing on `Mozilla Firefox` Iam getting the following Error-Message:

```
[error.service] An error occured: Object { _body: error, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: Object, type: 3, url: null }  app.e9e4671abf55fe5a53fc.js:936:46167

s</ConsoleLogger.prototype.error TheNameOfMyWebSite.net/js/app.e9e4671abf55fe5a53fc.js:936:46167
u</ErrorService.prototype.handleError TheNameOfMyWebSite.net/js/app.e9e4671abf55fe5a53fc.js:936:39646
u</CustomHttp.prototype.request/< TheNameOfMyWebSite.net/js/app.e9e4671abf55fe5a53fc.js:936:38047
a</CatchSubscriber.prototype.error TheNameOfMyWebSite.net/js/vendor.e9e4671abf55fe5a53fc.js:543:27790
a TheNameOfMyWebSite.js:311:808
[264]/</</</o</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask TheNameOfMyWebSite.net/js/polyfills.e9e4671abf55fe5a53fc.js:50:8316
onInvokeTask TheNameOfMyWebSite.js:176:9452
[264]/</</</o</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask TheNameOfMyWebSite.net/js/polyfills.e9e4671abf55fe5a53fc.js:50:8229
[264]/</</</n</Zone.prototype.runTask TheNameOfMyWebSite.net/js/polyfills.e9e4671abf55fe5a53fc.js:50:3362
ZoneTask/this.invoke TheNameOfMyWebSite.net/js/polyfills.e9e4671abf55fe5a53fc.js:50:9349


ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 0  for URL: null
Stack-Trace:
resolvePromise@TheNameOfMyWebSite.net/js/polyfills.e9e4671abf55fe5a53fc.js:57:1180
resolvePromise@TheNameOfMyWebSite.net/js/polyfills.e9e4671abf55fe5a53fc.js:57:796
scheduleResolveOrReject/<TheNameOfMyWebSite.net/js/polyfills.e9e4671abf55fe5a53fc.js:57:1803
[264]/</</</o</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@TheNameOfMyWebSite.net/js/polyfills.e9e4671abf55fe5a53fc.js:50:8316
onInvokeTask@TheNameOfMyWebSite.net/js/vendor.e9e4671abf55fe5a53fc.js:176:9452
[264]/</</</o</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@TheNameOfMyWebSite.net/js/polyfills.e9e4671abf55fe5a53fc.js:50:8229
[264]/</</</n</Zone.prototype.runTask@TheNameOfMyWebSite.net/js/polyfills.e9e4671abf55fe5a53fc.js:50:3362
drainMicroTaskQueue@TheNameOfMyWebSite.net/js/polyfills.e9e4671abf55fe5a53fc.js:50:367
ZoneTask/this.invoke@TheNameOfMyWebSite.net/js/polyfills.e9e4671abf55fe5a53fc.js:50:9396

defaultErrorLogger TheNameOfMyWebSite.net/js/vendor.e9e4671abf55fe5a53fc.js:8:473
ee</ErrorHandler.prototype.handleError TheNameOfMyWebSite.net/js/vendor.e9e4671abf55fe5a53fc.js:162:273
next TheNameOfMyWebSite.net/js/vendor.e9e4671abf55fe5a53fc.js:176:14602
Qe</EventEmitter.prototype.subscribe/i< TheNameOfMyWebSite.net/js/vendor.e9e4671abf55fe5a53fc.js:176:6258
c</SafeSubscriber.prototype.__tryOrUnsub TheNameOfMyWebSite.net/js/vendor.e9e4671abf55fe5a53fc.js:211:3724
c</SafeSubscriber.prototype.next TheNameOfMyWebSite.net/js/vendor.e9e4671abf55fe5a53fc.js:211:2960
u</Subscriber.prototype._next TheNameOfMyWebSite.net/js/vendor.e9e4671abf55fe5a53fc.js:211:1927
u</Subscriber.prototype.nextTheNameOfMyWebSite.net/js/vendor.e9e4671abf55fe5a53fc.js:211:1574
p</Subject.prototype.next TheNameOfMyWebSite.net/js/vendor.e9e4671abf55fe5a53fc.js:211:6849
Qe</EventEmitter.prototype.emit TheNameOfMyWebSite.net/js/vendor.e9e4671abf55fe5a53fc.js:176:6006
Xe</NgZone.prototype.triggerError TheNameOfMyWebSite.net/js/vendor.e9e4671abf55fe5a53fc.js:176:10237
onHandleError TheNameOfMyWebSite.net/js/vendor.e9e4671abf55fe5a53fc.js:176:9812
[264]/</</</o</ZoneDelegate.prototype.handleError TheNameOfMyWebSite.net/js/polyfills.e9e4671abf55fe5a53fc.js:50:7683
[264]/</</</n</Zone.prototype.runGuarded TheNameOfMyWebSite.net/js/polyfills.e9e4671abf55fe5a53fc.js:50:2951
[264]/</</</n.microtaskDrainDone/< TheNameOfMyWebSite.net/js/polyfills.e9e4671abf55fe5a53fc.js:57:2461
[264]/</</</n.microtaskDrainDone TheNameOfMyWebSite.net/js/polyfills.e9e4671abf55fe5a53fc.js:57:2430
drainMicroTaskQueue TheNameOfMyWebSite.net/js/polyfills.e9e4671abf55fe5a53fc.js:50:477
ZoneTask/this.invoke TheNameOfMyWebSite.net/js/polyfills.e9e4671abf55fe5a53fc.js:50:9396
```

But the website refreshes fine and everything works how it should, except for the error Iam receiving.

I only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38286250/exception-response-with-status-0-for-url-null-in-angular2) post, where the person had a similar problem.

Another person on Stackoverflow also had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38286250/exception-response-with-status-0-for-url-null-in-angular2?noredirect=1&lq=1), but since I am not using [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) because frontend and backend run on the same domain, this won't work for me.

What does this error message mean? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

This looks like a CORS issue.

> Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that allows restricted resources (e.g. fonts) on a web page to be requested from another domain outside the domain from which the first resource was served.

Read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Basically your Angular2 application is hosted on another server than the API you are calling.

Since you are using `ASP.NET Core 1.0 Web API`, I suggest you read through the Microsoft's [Enabling Cross-Origin Requests (CORS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors) documentation.

Comment: Hello @mercador thanks for your answer.

We are not using CORS, since backend and frontend are running on the same domain.

Comment: @MoritzSchmidt maybe your Firefox web browser has some plugin installed which block scripts?

Comment: Good idea but even if I deactivate all plugins Iam getting the same error :/ @mercador